# Ionic 2 app does not get JWT token from storage

Tags: angular, ionic2, jwt

I am using Ionic 2 final version with angular2-jwt plugin. I am successfully logging and receive token which I save to storage

```
this.storage.set('id_token', res.token);
```

Once I refresh the page and I try to check authorization in my auth.ts header never sends token. I understand that the problem is with async storage, but I don't know how to solve it. I tried many different solutions...

Also, when I save token in my constants it works perfectly fine.

My app.module.ts looks like this:

```
...

export function getAuthHttp(http) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
     noJwtError: true,
     globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-academy': 'academy'}],
     tokenGetter: () => storage.get('id_token'),
  }), http);
}

...

providers: [
   {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
   {provide: AuthHttp, useFactory: getAuthHttp, deps: [Http]}
 ...
]
```

And my auth.ts:

```
...
@Injectable()
export class Auth {

    serverUrl: string;
    storage: Storage = new Storage();  

    constructor(public http: Http,
          public authHttp: AuthHttp,
          public constantsService: ConstantsService,
    ) {                 
       this.serverUrl = this.constantsService.API_ENDPOINT();

    }

    login(credentials){ 
      let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-academy': 'academy' });
      return this.authHttp.post(this.serverUrl+'/login', JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
    }
    ....
    public checkAuthentication(){
       return this.authHttp.post(this.serverUrl+'/restricted',{})
    }
    ....
```

Thank you.

Comment: For people that might be looking at this code just to say it's all good. I forgot to set remember me to true... yes, I know...

Answer (score 0):

Change you getAuthHttp like this to use localStorage instead of ionic storage:

```
export function getAuthHttp(http) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    globalHeaders: [{'Accept': 'application/json'}],
    //tokenGetter: (() => storage.get('id_token').then((val)=>{return val}) ),
    tokenGetter: (() => JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("id_token"))),
    noJwtError: true,
    headerPrefix: "JWT",
  }), http);
}
```

As far as I can tell, the auth0 sdk is not using Ionic storage to store the id_token anyway... it's just using window.localStorage, so you might as well just use that too and its a synchronous method so avoids this promise stuff.